# problema al crear un nuevo proyecto android studio

Tags: android, gradle

Necesitaba ayuda con *android studio* **Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1** por que tengo que usarlo en una materia de la universidad y no puedo arrancar ya que me da este problema al crear un proyecto desde cero (ya intente todas las formas que encontre por aqui:

Versiones de gradle
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui va el error de la consola:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}.
Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\Fabrizio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
Cannot create mockable android.jar
C:\Users\Fabrizio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

En realidad es más largo pero me excedo el límite de caracteres.

---

con respecto al dispositivo ya lo instale no hubo problema pero al error de sync gradle no lo eh podido solucionar no encuentro forma aqui dejo una foto del sdk tools por si ven que me falta algo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te dice que no hay dispositivos. ¿Tienes algún disposito conectado o emulador configurado?

Comment: Hasta donde conozco no tiene nada que ver que te diga dispositivo desconectado o no tengas ninguno. Al parecer tienes problemas con las dependencias del propio _Android Studio_. Ejecuta _Android Studio_ como **Administrador** para que pruebes a ver si son **problemas de permisos** para escribir los archivos.

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto a el error:

> Cannot create mockable android.jar

Invalida caché y reinicia, ve a el menú de Android Studio y selecciona:
`Files` > `Invalidade Caches/Restart`

---

Posteriormente,si no tienes un dispositivo físico **debes crear y configurar un dispositivo virtual** para usarlo en Android Studio, revisa:

[Cómo crear y administrar dispositivos virtuales](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds?hl=es-419)

**Selecciona `Tools` > `AVD Manager`.
En la barra de herramientas, haz clic en `AVD Manager` Ícono del Administrador de AVD. Cuando crees un dispositivo virtual, puedes usarlo para cargar tu aplicación.**

Revisa : [Cómo crear un AVD](http://C%C3%B3mo%20crear%20un%20AVD)

1. Haz clic en `Tools` > `AVD Manager` para abrir el Administrador de AVD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Haz clic en `Create Virtual Device`, en la parte inferior del diálogo del Administrador de AVD. Aparecerá la página `Select Hardware`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que solo algunos perfiles de hardware incluyen `Play Store` por indicación. Esto indica que esos perfiles son totalmente compatibles con CTS y pueden usar imágenes del sistema que incluyan la app de Play Store.

3. Selecciona un perfil de hardware y haz clic en `Next`.
   Si no ves el perfil de hardware que deseas, puedes crear o importar uno.

Aparecerá la página `System Image`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Selecciona la imagen del sistema para un nivel de API determinado y haz clic en `Next`.
   En la pestaña `Recommended`, aparecen listas de imágenes de sistema recomendadas. En las otras pestañas, se incluye una lista más completa. En el panel derecho, se describe la imagen de sistema seleccionada. Las imágenes x86 son las que se ejecutan más rápido en el emulador.

Si ves `Download` junto a la imagen de sistema, debes hacer clic en la opción para descargarla. Para concretar la descarga, debes estar conectado a Internet.

El nivel de API del dispositivo de destino es importante, ya que no podrá ejecutarse tu app en una imagen del sistema con un nivel de API inferior al que se necesita, según se especifica en el atributo minSdkVersion del archivo de manifiesto de la app. Para obtener más información sobre la relación entre el nivel de API del sistema y minSdkVersion, consulta el Control de versiones de tus apps.

Si tu app declara un elemento  en el archivo de manifiesto, requerirá una imagen de sistema en la que se encuentre esa biblioteca externa. Si deseas ejecutar tu app en un emulador, crea un AVD que incluya la biblioteca obligatoria. Si lo haces, es posible que debas usar un componente complementario para la plataforma de AVD; por ejemplo, el complemento de las API de Google contiene la biblioteca de Google Maps.

Aparecerá la página `Verify Configuration`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. Modifica las propiedades de AVD según sea necesario y, luego, haz clic en Finish.
   Haz clic en `Show Advanced Settings` para que se muestren más configuraciones, como la máscara.

El nuevo AVD aparecerá en la página `Your Virtual Devices` o en el diálogo `Select Deployment Target`.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda hay agrege una imagen por si algo me falto de instalar , pero aun me sale el error de sync gradle

Answer (score -1):

Hola queria comentar que ya lo solucione instalando una version mas reciente como Android Bumblebee 2021.1.1 nose por que la Artic Fox no me funcionaba , gracias a todos los que comentaron saludos !